# Can't get rid of that white-alpha-border!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

If I press the "include alpha-button" in the Mix-Color-Node, I get white borders. Otherwise i've got a perfect alpha but no blue background.

[image: white-border problem]

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27169

Comment: Yes but i've concretize my question, I hope.

Comment: @user2649 If your original question was asking about the same thing (but was unclear), please edit the original instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Alpha Over Node instead of the mix node. Color -> Alpha Over

[image]

This will also work if you use an image instead of a RGB node.

[image]

Comment: and with an image?

Comment: what image? In your question you mention nothing of an image.

Comment: If I use an image instead of a RGB-Node.

Comment: yes it will still work

Comment: and when you now press only alpha-button. You will see a white outline

Comment: no, the outline is gone, I am not sure what you are doing. This should work just fine. Use my screenshots. Also the you don't need to feed a alpha channel into the viewer, nor do you need to enable use alpha.

Comment: (because I need a seperate alpha channel)

Comment: so you want to blue to be transparent?

Comment: for export to use it as an alpha mask

Comment: no the cube should be combined with an image and the alpha of the cube should be untouched

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27170

Comment: The alpha of the cube is untouched.

Comment: What i am supposed to do with the blend file? I am not really understanding your problem

Comment: there you can see the problem

Comment: I thought the problem was the white border around the cube? If this is a different problem you can post another question

Comment: Also I do not have the file white_border.jpg

Comment: yes there is a white border around the cube

Comment: Also jpeg does not support and alpha channel

Comment: i normaly use tiff etc.

Comment: @user2642 the reason there is a white border is because you saved it like that. There is no easy way to get rid of the white border when all the layers are merged and its all one image

Comment: Well save out the cube as an image that supports alpha

Comment: have you looked into the blend file?

Comment: yes I looked at the blend file. You need to reupload it. before you do that though go to File -> External Data -> Pack into .blend

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27171

Comment: Okay. The image in your blend file is a screenshot of the compositor with the cube and the white border as the backdrop image. Are you asking me how to remove the white border from the .jpg?

Comment: no, the image is irrelevant

Comment: you can use instead a blue, yellow etc colored background. But if I go to the viewer node i see a border

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/96YzD.jpg

Comment: if you just want the cube without the border do this  http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/9333/maw4.png

Comment: i need the copositing (cube and image) to save it into a tiff file. AND then i need an alpha-mask of the cube to save into the tiff file to(tu use it as an mask)

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean now

Comment: why do you need transparency for the back ground? Why bother giving the background a color if it is fully transparent anyway

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a mix node, Use an alpha-over node. Although blender shows you a border around the cube, it is actually doing what you want. Use the following node setup. You do not need a scale node per se, I only have it because the background image is larger than the cube render

[image]

If you were to export a render with the shown node setup and import it into another compositing application you would see that this is the correct method. The alpha is retained and the composite shows the default backdrop from when you rendered it out of blender, but you can easily change that since the alpha is retained.

[image]

The alpha channel as viewed in another 3d app.

[image]

The node setup

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you lower the Width in the Film Panel under the render tab from `1.0` to `0.01` the border will dissolve.

[image]

Comment: This is not the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: The width is used for smoother antialiasing. The higher the pixel filter value (width), the smoother the aliasing. Values below 1 results in sharper renderings.