# shadow catcher + diffuse indirect to have color in the shadows

Tags: node-editor, shadows

How can I make a red sphere on a shadow catcher plane being visible?
I mean: the final image is a red sphere laid on a background image with a shadow, BUT in this shadow I wish to get a bit of red.(from the diffuse indirect)
Hope someone can understand what I looking for. I found some tuto on this but without the shadow catcher…

thanks for any help.
G.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add color to shadow catcher](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88628/add-color-to-shadow-catcher)

Comment: Hello Cegaton, I saw this tips which is great. But in my case it is not exactly the same problem.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage

Comment: read: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/lets-finally-fix-the-shadowcatcher/691